# Cannot obtain debugging symbols for dumps

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, crash-dumps

Trying to debug minidump in windbg/VS. Cannot get symbols for `msvcr90` of version `9.0.30729.8387`. Was trying to do `.symfix`. If I set sympath for my application symbols, I can get part of call stack which of my code, but not of msvcr. If I use `.symfix`, partially I can get several calls from c runtime, but, obviously, not from my code.

`!sym noisy` without `.symfix`:

```
SYMSRV:  \\eserver\symstore\ms\msvcr90.dll\51EA1BBDa3000\msvcr90.dll not found
SYMSRV:  \\eserver\symstore\ms\msvcr90.dll\51EA1BBDa3000\msvcr90.dll not found
SYMSRV:  \\eserver\symstore\ms\msvcr90.dll\51EA1BBDa3000\msvcr90.dll not found
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/msvcr90.dll/51EA1BBDa3000/msvcr90.dll not found
DBGHELP: C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)\msvcr90.dll - file not found
SYMSRV:  \\eserver\symstore\ms\msvcr90.dll\51EA1BBDa3000\msvcr90.dll not found
SYMSRV:  \\eserver\symstore\ms\msvcr90.dll\51EA1BBDa3000\msvcr90.dll not found
SYMSRV:  \\eserver\symstore\ms\msvcr90.dll\51EA1BBDa3000\msvcr90.dll not found
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/msvcr90.dll/51EA1BBDa3000/msvcr90.dll not found
DBGENG:  C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.8387_none_08e793bfa83a89b5\msvcr90.dll - Couldn't map image from disk.
Unable to load image C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.8387_none_08e793bfa83a89b5\msvcr90.dll, Win32 error 0n2
DBGENG:  msvcr90.dll - Partial symbol image load missing image info
DBGHELP: Module is not fully loaded into memory.
DBGHELP: Searching for symbols using debugger-provided data.
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for msvcr90.dll
```

The last thing I can see with this is call from `msvcr90!_freefls`. In all ways I can get only part of call stack and I need full. Is there a way to obtain right symbols? Similiar problem with symbols for `9.0.30729.6871`.

Client OS: Windows Server 2012 (build 9200) 64-bit, Windows 7 (build 7600) 64-bit, Windows Vista (build 6000) 64-bit, Windows Server 2008 R2 (build 7600) 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with reproducing problem on client OS with attached debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple symbol paths so the debugger can get symbols from multiple places.

```
.Symfix
```

Is a good first command to run.
Then use

```
.sympathy+ c:\<My_symbols>
```

The other problem above is

```
Couldn't map image from disk.
```

that comes from

```
DBGENG:  C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.8387_none_08e793bfa83a89b5\msvcr90.dll - Couldn't map image from disk.
Unable to load image C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.8387_none_08e793bfa83a89b5\msvcr90.dll, Win32 error 0n2
DBGENG:  msvcr90.dll - Partial symbol image load missing image info
DBGHELP: Module is not fully loaded into memory.
```

I would make another copy of that file and point your symbol path to that to see if the debugger can load it from there.

Comment: At beginning I have had both MS symbol server and my local folder in the symbols path. And it doesn't work properly. That's why I had to use `.symfix`. I don't have library of version `9.0.30729.8387`. If I had, I wouldn't ask my question. I don't know why windbg mentioned this file.

Comment: It should definitely work. Can you do `.symfix` then add your local symbol path, then `!sym noisy` and share the full output of `.reload; k`

Comment: Nothing. Here it is: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vHEEbX4n3aO5dwXjLtgaGMiEiij1lXdMfq8wPYwxFTE/edit?usp=sharing.